# .htaccess rewrite, how do I do it for this scenario?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to have

eg.

www.domain.com/api/json/implode/abc/and/a/b/c...

equal to

www.domain.com/api/jason/?method=implode&key=abc&param1=and&param2=a&param3=b&param4=c...

Comment: Was that meant to be "jason" or "json"? :-)

Comment: I guess he used `jason` in the rewritten URL to avoid conflicting with the original URL.

Comment: LOL, it's a typo sorry!!!!!! should have been www.domain.com/api/json/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/api/json/([/]*)/([/]*)$ /api/jason/method=$1&key=$2
RewriteRule ^/api/json/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)$ /api/jason/method=$1&key=$2&param1=$3
RewriteRule ^/api/json/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)$ /api/jason/method=$1&key=$2&param1=$3&param2=$4
RewriteRule ^/api/json/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)$ /api/jason/method=$1&key=$2&param1=$3&param2=$4&param3=$5
RewriteRule ^/api/json/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)/([/]*)$ /api/jason/method=$1&key=$2&param1=$3&param2=$4&param3=$5&param4=$6
# keep expanding this pattern out for however many paramas you need to be
# able to handle...
```

But cleaner would be something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/api/json/([/]*)/([/]*)$ /api/jason/method=$1&key=$2
RewriteRule ^/api/json/([/]*)/([/]*)/(.*)$ /api/jason/method=$1&key=$2&params=$3
```

ie: stuff all trailing optional params into a single parameter.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I know having more than 10 parameters is silly, but I would like to know if there is a programmatic way to do this?

Comment: @James Lin: If you have so many unnamed parameters, why do you need them to be separate parameters in the first place?

Comment: @casablanca because from the URL wise looks cleaner
eg. www.domain.com/api/json/add/1/2
    www.domain.com/api/json/multiply/1/2/3

Comment: @James Lin: Your URL would still look the same, you would just pass the last bunch of parameters directly to your script (eg. 1/2/3) and then split them up there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to dynamically figure out the number of `param`s, but you can do something close:

```
RewriteRule ^/api/json/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*) /api/jason/?method=$1&key=$2&params=$3
```

This will extract `method` and `key` individually but put all the additional parameters into `params`, which you can split later within your script.